# How to work out what GREFs are being used in MonoDroid?

Tags: garbage-collection, xamarin.android

When using the emulator on this project - https://github.com/davidhauck/MvxSampleCode - I'm seeing a lot of messages like:

```
  09-03 19:08:47.015 I/monodroid-gc(  473): 1813 outstanding GREFs. Performing a full GC!
```

This document - http://docs.xamarin.com/android/advanced_topics/garbage_collection - provides a good background to why this is happening, but it doesn't help me work out what objects are actually being referenced.

In MonoTouch I know there's a good profiler, but I don't think there's anything similar available in Mono for Android? Is there any way I can walk the current heap to find out what the GREFs are?

Comment: I don't think that you can. GREFs are global references related to JNI. If you can profile JNI you should be able to see them.